# How to create Subtask in TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs, scrum

I want to create User Story (PBI)-->Task---> Sub task. How can we create this hierarchy in TFS 2012? I could try only two levels PBI and Tasks. I could not create Sub tasks under Tasks.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible, see this screen
[image]

The query needs to be a "Tree of workitems" to get the output.
To create the structure I've went the following path:

- create PBI
- add child task in the PBI detail
- open the newly added task
- go to the links tab on the right bottom pane
- add a link to a new or existing workitem as a child